# How to show all comments in foreach with article title within Laravel 5 Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I am following a tutorial Articles and comments.
Below works fine, but how do i get all comments with the articlename in a foreach?

Model: Article

```
namespace App\Http\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{  
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Models\Comment');
}
protected $fillable = array('title','body');
}
```

Model: Comments

```
namespace App\Http\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{  
public function article() {
    return $this->belongs('Article');
}
protected $fillable = array('body','article_id');


}
```

Example dump in ArticleController:

```
$items = Article::find(1)->comments()->get();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    print_r($item->body);
}
```

Comment: Does Article have an associated model of Catagory with a name property?

Comment: @Leo this is what i have, what do i miss?

Comment: I don't know! what is categoryname? what is its relationship to articles or comments?

Comment: Sorry i mean a articlename instead of categoryname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) on querying relations

```
$article = Article::find(1);

echo $article->name;

foreach ($article->comments as $comment) {
    //
}
```

Comment: thanks. Almost there i think. De foreach loop is ok, but i want also the articlename into the foreach loop what belongs to the comment. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Its the same article name  each comment though ?

Comment: Worked, how can i get all comments and not by find(1)

Comment: Worked! foreach ( $comments as $comment) {
    echo $comment->body.' - '.$comment->article->title.'<br>';
}

Answer (score 0):

In the CommentController i dumped for example:

```
foreach ( $comments as $comment) {
    echo $comment->body.' - '.$comment->article->title.'<br>';
}
```